# How to merge two differently sized dataframes based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes based on a date column with this code:

```
data_df = (pd.merge(data, one_min_df, on='date', how='outer'))
```

The first dataframe has 3784 columns and the second dataframe has 3764. Every date in the second dataframe is also within the first dataframe. I would like to get the dataframes to merge on the date column with any dates that the longer dataframe has being left as blank or NaN etc.

The code I have here gives the 3764 values followed by 20 empty rows, rather than correctly matching them.

Comment: hard to debug without a reproducible example

Comment: Should the code I am using work?

Comment: you should first refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
one_min_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(one_min_df['date'])
data_df = pd.merge(data, one_min_df, on='date', how='left')
```

Comment: The datetime format is the same between the two dataframes.

Comment: I did that just for completeness. From your code it was not clear that `date` format is same across 2 dataset. Did you get `3784` observations with this code?

Comment: Length of First dataframe is 3784 and length of second is 3764. Then the length of the new column is 3784, with 20 blank rows from 3764 - 3784.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. The new data should have `3784` observations with `new column` having 20 rows `NaN`. This `new column` will be coming from `second dataset`. My question is did the code I shared giving you this answer? It should. If not, then provide us an example data.